# Make pynput mouse listener less resource-hungry

Tags: python, python-3.x, resources, listener, pynput

I'm trying to use [This](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/mouse.html#monitoring-the-mouse) script from pynput to monitor my mouse, but its too resource-intensive.

Tried to `import time` and add `time.sleep(1)` after `on_move(x, y)` function but when you run it your mouse drives crazy.

Here's the overall code:

```
import time

def on_move(x, y):
    print('Pointer moved to {0}'.format((x, y)))
    time.sleep(1) # <<< Tried to add it over here cuz it takes most of the process.

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('{0} at {1}'.format('Pressed' if pressed else 'Released', (x, y)))
    if not pressed:
        return False

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    print('Scrolled {0}'.format((x, y)))
with Listener(on_move=on_move, on_click=on_click, on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a thread to run your code when do some task which will block your code.(In your code, `sleep(1)` will block the code),Whatever, this works fine on my PC:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import time
import threading

def task(): # this is what you want to do.
    time.sleep(1)  # <<< Tried to add it over here cuz it takes most of the process.
    print("After sleep 1 second")

def on_move(x, y):
    print('Pointer moved to {0}'.format((x, y)))
    threading.Thread(target=task).start() # run some tasks here.

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('{0} at {1}'.format('Pressed' if pressed else 'Released', (x, y)))
    if not pressed:
        return False

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    print('Scrolled {0}'.format((x, y)))


with Listener(on_move=on_move, on_click=on_click, on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    listener.join()
```